# how get a multidimensional-array of a string delimited with parentheses?

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing, multidimensional-array

how is the most efficient form of converting text with nested parentheses in a nested array?
Here's an example:

```
$input="((A = 8) AND((BC > 5 OR DE < 3) OR (FG = ALPHA))"

$output=array(
    [A>] => 8,
    [AND] =array(
             [BC>]=>5,
             [OR]=array([DE<]=>3)
              ),
    [OR]=>array([FG=]=>alpha)

)
```

Or another possible solution that will also serve

```
$output=array(
    [A] =>array(['operator']=>'>',['value']=>8),
    [AND] =array(
             [BC>]=array(['operator']=>'>',['value']=>5),
             [OR]=array([DE]=>array(['operator']=>'<',['value']=>3))
              ),
    [OR]=>array([FG]=>array(['operator']=>'=',['value']=>3))

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it could looks like this (other choices can be made, but assuming you will want to evaluate the statement, I think this works nicely):

```
$operand = array("sum", array(
    "op1" => array("sum", array(
        "op1" => array("lit", "A")
        "op" => "AND"
        "op2" => array("lit", "8")
    )),
    "op" => "AND"
    "op2" => array("sum", array(
        "op1" => array("sum", /* .. */)
        "op" => "OR"
        "op2" => array("sum", /* .. */)
    ))
))
```

Your grammar is:

```
sum: operand operation operand
operand: sum | lit
lit: string
operation: OR | AND | = | < | >
```

Comment: yes, my grammar is that but with some operator more. I do not know how to tokenize the string because I do not use tokenize functions I do not understand them

Comment: Look at parsers. They're surprisingly simple to write. Tokenize the string, interpret it (resolve ambiguous situations like: `a < b AND c > d`) and build your nested structure.

Comment: Thanks, I know a little of how parsers works, but I do not dominate it, I try to find a solution to this problem with php, I do not know if there are opportunities to parser this in php.